# Powerpoint file downloaded from Sharepoint gets ruined by upstream changes in bizarre fashion

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, onedrive, sharepoint

I downloaded a pptx file from our company's Sharepoint repository (by right-clicking and choosing 'Download'). Then I moved the file on to my Desktop, which is synchronized into OneDrive. Then I made a lot of changes to this file on my Desktop.

When I opened the file today, the contents were completely messed up, with a completely different design, different slide order, some of my content missing, and random other content overlaying mine.

I checked the original file I started from in Sharepoint, and it reflects these changes - it has a different design to before, a different slide order etc etc. But strangely, none of the revision dates line up though: I originally downloaded the file on the 14th July, whereas the last update to the file in Sharepoint was on the 7th July.

Right-clicking on my copy of the file in OneDrive, it claims that all the revisions to the file were made myself. Reverting to a previous version does not restore my content - all the historical versions are also ruined.

What has happened here, how do I recover my content, and how do I stop it from happening again?